# Excel VBA - why is my output value placed one cell down than expected?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a weird fluke that can be fixed easily, but I'd like to know why it's happening in the first place. I have a subroutine that is spitting out its value one cell down than expected. Here's the code:

```
Sub Reference()

On Error Resume Next
Dim Output_Row As Long

Output_Row = Range("Table1[Output]").Row

For Each cl In Range("Table1[ID1]")
    Range("Table1[Output]").Cells(Output_Row, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Table2[ID2]"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cl, Range("Table2[ID2]"), 0))
    Output_Row = Output_Row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

Now this should perform like a VLOOKUP and regurgitate the same ID from Table2 if it matches Table1, otherwise be blank. But this happens whenever I run it:

[image]

See how all the outputs are one cell down from where they should be? Now I can redefine Output_Row to say:

```
Output_Row = Range("Table1[Output]").Row - 1
```

That realigns the output values in the right spots. But I would like to know how it got wrong in the first place. Any thoughts?

Comment: Edit: Linked the wrong picture! Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range.Row` always returns the row number relative to the ENTIRE sheet.
On the other hand `Range.Cells` takes relative values.

So here you are passing an absolute value from `Range("Table1[Output]").Row` into a function expecting a relative value. The relative value is offset by the position of the table on the sheet AND the table header row `Range("Table1[Output]").Cells(Output_Row, 1)`.

Comment: I knew there was something I was overlooking, thank you! I'll have to make a note of that in my sub for future reference.

Comment: You probably just want output_row = 1

Comment: Yeah that would simplify it even moreso, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the location of **Output_Row** increment

Sub Reference()

On Error Resume Next

Dim Output_Row As Long

For Each cl In Range("Table1[ID1]")

Output_Row = Output_Row + 1

Range("Table1[Output]").Cells(Output_Row, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Table2[ID2]"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cl, Range("Table2[ID2]"), 0))

Next cl

End Sub